# file_get_contents($url) Erro retornado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, eu achei um função aqui no stack para um problema parecido com o meu porém estou tendo um problema.

A função é:

```
function file_get_contents_retry($url, $attemptsRemaining=3) {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $attemptsRemaining--;

    if( empty($content) && $attemptsRemaining > 0 ) {
        return file_get_contents_retry($url, $attemptsRemaining);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Meu problema é que após pegar as informações eu tenho um `echo "sucesso";` que retorna para uma função $.post.

Porém, me parece que quando a função da algum erro em alguma tentativa, o $.post, além de pegar o sucesso do echo ele pega essa erro.

Eu preciso saber como fazer para remover esse erro.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Esse $url é um path (arquivo local) ou é uma URL (http) mesmo?

Comment: @W.Faustino é uma URL http mesmo.

Comment: Alguns servers bloqueiam o fopen ou o file_get_contents, acho que a melhor solução é usar o cURL do PHP http://www.php.net/curl

Comment: @W.Faustino o site não bloqueia. O problema é que algumas vezes ele da problema para abrir, e outras ele abre corretamente. A função ela tenta 3x. Como exemplo, digamos que na primeira tentativa ela falhe e na segunda funcione. Quando eu pego o retorno que eu gostaria que fosse apenas o "sucesso" ele retorna além do sucesso o erro da primeira tentativa.

Comment: Qual a versão do PHP vc está usando? Se for PHP 7 tenta usar um try catch.

Comment: @W.Faustino a versão do php é a 5.6.31. Try catch funciona apenas com o PHP 7?

Answer (score 0):

Substitui a primeira linha da função por:

```
$content=@file_get_contents($url);
```

Fica assim:

```
function file_get_contents_retry($url, $attemptsRemaining=3) {
    $content = @file_get_contents($url);
    $attemptsRemaining--;

    if( empty($content) && $attemptsRemaining > 0 ) {
        return file_get_contents_retry($url, $attemptsRemaining);
    }

    return $content;
}
```